# Listening for Cookie, Refreshing page when set - Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, listener

I am using a popup plugin which sets a cookie.

I've restricted content to those with the cookie in single.php like so:

```
<?php if(isset($_COOKIE['pum-88881'])){
the_content();
}
else {
    echo apply_filters( 'the_content', wp_trim_words( strip_tags( $post->post_content ), 55 ) )  . '<p>The full article is only available to subscribers to our newsletter.<a class="opensub">Subscribe to our Newsletter to Continue Reading</a></p>';
}
?>
```

This code works. When there is a cookie with the value pum-88881, the full content is displayed. Only problem is, it requires a refresh.

So, to try and remedy this, I've been trying to write a listener in Javascript:

```
function getCookie(c_name) {
var c_value = document.cookie,
    c_start = c_value.indexOf(" " + c_name + "=");
if (c_start == -1) c_start = c_value.indexOf(c_name + "=");
if (c_start == -1) {
    c_value = null;
} else {
    c_start = c_value.indexOf("=", c_start) + 1;
    var c_end = c_value.indexOf(";", c_start);
    if (c_end == -1) {
        c_end = c_value.length;
    }
    c_value = unescape(c_value.substring(c_start, c_end));
}
return c_value;
}
setTimeout(function(){
var username = getCookie("pum-88881");
if (username != "") {     

    }
    else{
location.reload()
    }
}, 1000);
```

It is not working. No messages in the console.

What say ye?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this is related to Popup Maker I'll post this here. Assuming your setting the cookie on close you would use something like this.

```
jQuery('#pum-88881').on('pumAfterClose', function () {
    window.location.reload(true);
});
```